# Want to keep username@hostname of hadoop slaves different

Tags: hadoop, hadoop2, ubuntu-16.04

I am setting a `hadoop-2.7.3` multi-node cluster. For adding slave node i edited the slave file and `/etc/hosts` file. Also I added ssh pass key to them Now after executing `start-dfs.sh` the hadoop connects to `user1@myStyle` which is me, its all right till here. But now instead of connecting to other node having name `user2@node1` it connects to `user1@node1` which does not exists. So, how can I connect to `user2@node1` instead of `user1@node1`

```
OS:-Ubuntu 16.04
Hadoop Version:-2.7.3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Step-1:

The slaves file must have entries in the form (one machine name per line):

```
machine_hostname1

machine_hostname2
...
```

In the above, each line represents the actual name of the machine in the cluster and must be exactly the same as specified in /etc/hosts file.

Step-2:

Check whether you are manually able to connect to each machine by using the following command:

```
ssh -i ~/.ssh/<"keyfilename"> <"username">@publicNameOfMachine
```

Don't type the quotes or angle-brackets in the above command, and replace the components with the names you have chosen.

Step-3:

If you are not able to connect manually, then either your key file is not correct, or it has not been placed in the .ssh directory on the target machine, or it does not Linux 600 permission for the file.

Step-4:

Do you have a config file on the NameNode under .ssh directory. That file should have entries like the following 4 lines per machine:

```
Host <"ShortMachineName">

HostName <"MachinePublicName">

User <"username">

IdentityFile ~/.ssh/<keyfilename>
```

Don't type the quotes or angle-brackets in the above 4 commands, and replace the components with the names you have chosen. These 4 lines are per machine.

Make sure you are not repeating (cut-paste error) the username and/or machine name for each machine. It must match what username and machine names you have configured.

Comment: can you elaborate the step-4, I don't have the NameNode conf file under .ssh directory

Comment: In case anyone else needs it, more info about step 4 can be found here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51822209/hadoop-cluster-hadoop-user-ssh-communication