# Hadoop Cluster - "hadoop" user ssh communication

Tags: hadoop, ssh, hadoop2

I am setting up Hadoop 2.7.3 cluster on EC2 servers - 1 NameNode, 1 Secondary NameNode and 2 DataNodes.

Hadoop core uses SSH for communication with slaves to launch the processes on the slave node.

1. Do we need to have same SSH keys on all the nodes for the hadoop user?
2. What is the best practice/ideal way to copy or add the NameNode to Slave nodes SSH credentials?

Answer (score 1):

> Do we need to have same SSH keys on all the nodes for the hadoop user?

- The same public key needs to be on all of the nodes

> What is the best practice/ideal way to copy or add the NameNode to
>   Slave nodes SSH credentials?

**[Per documentation:](https://www.novixys.com/blog/setup-apache-hadoop-cluster-aws-ec2/)**

**Namenode: Password Less SSH**

> Password-less SSH between the name nodes and the data nodes. Let us
>   create a public-private key pair for this purpose on the namenode.

```
namenode> ssh-keygen
```

> Use the default (`/home/ubuntu/.ssh/id_rsa`) for the key location and
>   hit enter for an empty passphrase.

**Datanodes: Setup Public Key**

> The public key is saved in `/home/ubuntu/.ssh/id_rsa.pub`. We need to
>   copy this file from the namenode to each data node and append the
>   contents to /home/ubuntu/.ssh/authorized_keys on each data node.

```
datanode1> cat id_rsa.pub >> ~/.ssh/authorized_keys
datanode2> cat id_rsa.pub >> ~/.ssh/authorized_keys
datanode3> cat id_rsa.pub >> ~/.ssh/authorized_keys
```

**Namenode: Setup SSH Config**

> SSH uses a configuration file located at ~/.ssh/config for various
>   parameters. Set it up as shown below. Again, substitute each node’s
>   Public DNS for the HostName parameter (for example, replace 
>   with EC2 Public DNS for NameNode).

```
Host nnode
  HostName <nnode>
  User ubuntu
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa

Host dnode1
  HostName <dnode1>
  User ubuntu
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa

Host dnode2
  HostName <dnode2>
  User ubuntu
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa

Host dnode3
  HostName <dnode3>
  User ubuntu
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa
```

> At this point, verify that password-less operation works on each node
>   as follows (the first time, you will get a warning that the host is
>   unknown and whether you want to connect to it. Type yes and hit enter.
>   This step is needed once only):

```
namenode> ssh nnode
namenode> ssh dnode1
namenode> ssh dnode2
namenode> ssh dnode3
```

Comment: thanks Petro ! I followed all the above mentioned steps but when I try to ssh from NN to any DN, I am getting following error:Permission denied (publickey).
I checked, that the permission on all the files under .ssh folder is correct. Any idea, what could be the problem here?

Comment: Make sure the .ssh folder permissions are correct as well

Comment: Example of proper permissions:

`chmod 700 /home/myuser/.ssh`
`chmod 644 /home/myuser/.ssh/authorized_keys`

Comment: Thanks ! The steps are working fine in public EC2 AMIs but not working for custom AMI built by my company, I am checking the SSH configs for this AMI.